# Fastest way to iterate through the oldest items in an array? (Fastest implementation of a queue)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, queue, iteration

**See edit too**

I'm working in JavaScript but readable psuedocode of any kind may be able to answer my question.

I'm going to struggle describing this so please feel free to comment clarifications - I will answer them and refine my post accordingly.

**Essentially,** I have an array that acts as a queue, items are added, and when they are processed they need to be removed and more will eventually be added. What is the fastest way to get the first item in an array when I don't care about the index? I just want to iterate on a first-added basis without having to shift all entries in the array down each time. Also worth mentioning I am not looping through the array, I have a master loop for my app that checks if the array has items on each loop, and if it does, it will grab that data then remove it from the array. Currently to do this quickly I use pop, but now recognize I need to get the oldest item in the queue first each time, not the newest.

For more clarification if needed:

In my app I have blocks of raw data that first need to be ran through a function to be ready to be used by other parts of my app. Each block has a unique ID that I pass to the function in order for it to be parsed. For optimization purposes I only parse the blocks of data as it is needed.

In order to do this, my current system is when I realize I need a block to be parsed, I push its unique ID into an array, then a continuous loop in my app checks said array constantly, seeing if it has items in it. If it does, it pops the last item of the array and passes the unique id into the parsing function.

For performance reasons, on each iteration of the loop, only one block of data can be parsed. The issue arises when multiple blocks of data are in queue array already, and I add more items to the array before the loop can finish passing the already existing ID's in the array to the function. Basically, new ID's that are needed to be parsed are added to the end of the array before my loop can clear them out.

Now, this isn't all too bad because new data is needed somewhat sparsely, but when it is, lots of ID's are added at once, and this is an attribute of the app I can't really change.

Since I'm using pop, the most recently added ID is obviously always parsed first, but I chose this method as I believed it to be the fastest way to iterate a queue like this. However, I've come to realize I would rather parse the oldest items in the list first.

In essence, I'm looking for a way to loop through an array oldest to newest without having to re-organize the array each time. The index of the array is not important, I just need first-added, first-parsed behavior.

For example, I know I could always just pass the 0th item in the array to my function then shift the rest of the entries down, however, I believe having to shift down the rest of the items in the array is too costly to performance and not really worth it. If I'm just dumb and that should have no real-world cost please let me know, but still it seems like a band-aid fix. I'm certain there is a better solution out there.

I'm open to other data structures too as the array only holds strings.

Thank you

EDIT: While doing more googling I'm having a face palm moment and realized the problem I'm describing is a stack vs a queue. But now my question moves to what is the fastest implementation of a queue when the index isn't really of value to me?

Comment: An array with a head index whouldn't work for your purpose?

Comment: @HWSiew if my understanding of what a head index is is correct then no because I will clear the array and it will sit empty for long stretches of time until batches are added. For this reason I don't necessarily see an easy way to keep track of the index.

Comment: hmm.. I am abit confuse if you can elaborate more. A queue is a FIFO data structure. the head index of a queue is null when it is empty and head index is updated only when first item is added or an item is removed. this should be pretty straight forward operation with add() & remove()

Comment: However, this approach may use more space as no items are actually removed from the array. An other approach is using linked list for queue implementation.

Comment: FIFO is exactly what I need, maybe I confused my self above. Lets say I add 10 new items ordered item1 through 10. Currently item 10 is processed and popped first, but I need item 1 processed and removed first. I understand a shift method does this, but I don't necessarily need to re-index the array. I thought there would be a better solution than that.

Comment: @HWSiew yeah I need the items removed. Is there an implementation of an unordered list in javascript?

Comment: let arr = [1, ... , 10], head = 0, 
// process 1 with  arr[head++] and increase head by 1  
I don't see why 10 is process first?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/double-ended-queue

Comment: @Ry- wow, this package is exactly what I was looking for. Tysm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the FIFO queue implementation using singly linked list in javascript.

For more information of linked list -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/

```js
// queue implementation with linked list
var ListNode = function(val,next = null){
  
  this.val  = val 
  this.next = next

};

var Queue = function(){
  
  let head = null;
  let tail = null;
  
  this.show = function(){
    
    let curr = head;
    let q = [];
    
    while(curr){
      q.push(curr.val);
      curr = curr.next;
    }
    
    return q.join(' -> ');
  }
  
  this.enqueue = function(item){
    
    let node = new ListNode(item);
    if(!head) {
      head = node;
      tail = node;
    } else {
      tail.next = node;
      tail = node;
    }
    
  }
  
  this.dequeue = function(){
    
    if(!head) return null;
    else {
    
      let first = head;
      head = head.next;
      
      first.next = null;
      
      return first;
    }
    
  }
  
}

var myQueue = new Queue();
myQueue.enqueue(1); // head -> 1 
console.log(myQueue.show())
myQueue.enqueue(2); // head -> 1 -> 2
console.log(myQueue.show())
myQueue.enqueue(3); // head -> 1 -> 2 -> 3
console.log(myQueue.show())
myQueue.dequeue(); // head -> 2 -> 3
console.log(myQueue.show())
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer since this works and is fast from my quick jsbench, but the package in the comments above is actually even faster so I ended up going with that. Thank you for your help!